# How can I position long tables at multicolumn

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I am trying to print two long table which are can't be fit into one page side to side at multicolumns. The problem is whenever realize the table which is continuing along pages with *longtable* and *multicol*, they start not to be positioned side to side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest way is to take the two tables and use your text editor to merge them into one table with more columns then they maybe set as a standard singe (page-)column longtable.

Comment: While merging the two table to one are there any way to keep the space between tables (to show the merged table like two seperate table - e.g. the horizontal table line should not be shown this middle space )?

Comment: you can add space between the two halves by `@{\hspace{3cm}}` you would have to use `\cline` rather than `\hline` so lines didn't cross the whole thing. Not ideal but TeX doesn't really support  two parallel flows both taking part in page breaking. It is possible to have a custom output routine for one table that saves everything in boxes and then a custom output routine for the second that adds one page box from the first table each time it outputs a page but it would mean extensive rewrites to longtable internals.